# How do you order by column within a row in sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have a table that looks something like this

```
ATT A | ATT B
-------------
A     | B
D     | C
E     | F
H     | G
```

and instead I want a table that looks like:

```
ATT A | ATT B
-------------
A     | B
C     | D
E     | F
G     | H
```

How would I go about doing that? I'm using SQLite.

Comment: Ummm....there is no row in your first table in which the column `ATT A` (badly designed column name, BTW, as column names shouldn't have spaces in them) has a value of `C`.

Comment: @JackManey, I think that's the whole point of the question. The values in the second (and fourth) row are swapped ('order within a row').

Comment: SQL's keywords are primarily set up to work on columns (or individual fields), not rows. I have no idea why you'd want to do this, but regardless, SQL is the wrong tool to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Also, what if the columns have completely different data types? You need to carefully think through what you're doing.

Comment: I don't understand why D changes between the columns and nothing else does. Can you explain?

Comment: @Ben - The values in the fourth row have changed as well.  Basically, the OP is making the mistake of wanting to treat his/her RDBMS as though it was Excel.

Comment: Could you explain to us why you would want to order entries within a row? I'm really curious as to what's your reason for this particular question.

Comment: @JackManey, you're correct, of course. I still don't understand why unless it's based on the modulus of 2, which is tenuous at best,

Comment: I agree with the comments, but often people ask a simple question so they can solve a much more difficult problem.  Aside from the quirks mentioned, there is a simple solution.

Comment: I apologize for the badly named columns and such. I just put random info there. The main point, as some people have mentioned, was to swap the values of a column in a row such that they are in order. Both columns have the same type because they come from the same original column. This was a part of a query that I had trouble with and wanted to give the simplest version of the problem.

Comment: Did you try the answer below?  Does it work in SQLite?

Comment: I didn't have access to my computer this weekend, but checked it today and it worked great! Thank you for seeing through the inadvertent syntactical blunderings of a SQL noob and addressing the question at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has a `case .. end` expression that you can use inline in the SQL statement.  I think SQLite uses the same syntax.  This does what you asked for in SQL Server:

```
create table #temp (AttA char(1), AttB char(1))

insert into #temp valueS ('A', 'B'), ('D', 'C'), ('E', 'F'), ('H', 'G')

select * from #temp

select case when AttA < AttB then AttA else AttB end as AttA,
       case when AttB > AttA then AttB else AttA end as AttB
from   #temp

drop table #temp
```

Comment: Just checked that there is a "case when" supported in sqlite. This proposal works fine.

Comment: `CASE ... END` is an expression, not function.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing the columns have the same type and you just have 2 columns to reorder, you can rely on the min/max functions. With sqlite, when provided with multiple parameters, these functions do not aggregate data from multiple rows.

```
create table mytable( ATTA char, ATTB char );
insert into mytable values ('A', 'B');
insert into mytable values ('D', 'C');
insert into mytable values ('E', 'F');
insert into mytable values ('H', 'G') ;

select min(ATTA,ATTB),max(ATTA,ATTB) from mytable order by 1,2 ;
A|B
C|D
E|F
G|H
```

The min/max functions reorder the values in the columns. The order by clause reorders the rows. I think it cannot be generalized to more than 2 columns, except by writing a user defined C function to be called from sqlite.